# Consecutive asynchronous test steps in ava

Tags: javascript, testing, fixtures, ava

## The problem

The popular [ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava) package features a simple and powerful testing framework for javascript:

```js
import test from 'ava';

test('single step', t => {
    t.is('bar', 'bar');
    t.end();
});
```

Testing is dead simple for synchronous code. However, I am not sure how to write tests with multiple, consecutive, dependent steps.

For example, I would like to test a REST API. I would like to create a resource using `POST`, make sure it exists with `GET` call, and delete it with `DELETE`.

Needless to say, the order matters: the `POST` call must be finished before the `GET` call can start, and sometimes we even want a sleep time between steps.

## What have I tried

- Tried a series of `setTimeout`s where where the callback of each call is the next test step. It is fairly unreadable.

## My question

What's the right way to write a test with multiple consecutive steps with `ava`?

These steps are asynchronous and consecutive

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to have all these steps in a single test, make sure you can get promises out of your request library. Then use `async` / `await`.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix slow functions and logic into complex scenarios if you run your code via sequential executor [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs). You just need to write your code as if it was synchronous, and put it into function:

```
function process() {
    var data = jQueryGetJSON(nsynjsCtx, "data/index.json").data; // ajax call to get some data
    for(var i in data) { // data is ready at this point
        var resp = jQueryGetJSON(nsynjsCtx, "data/"+data[i]).data;  // another ajax call
        // ... resp is ready here, do processing of resp...
        nsynWait(nsynjsCtx,100); // wait 100ms
    }
    return someResult;
}
```

Then you run that function via nsynjs:

```
nsynjs.run(process,this,function (someResult) {
    console.log('done');
    // put t.end() inside this callback
});
```

See more examples here: https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/tree/master/examples